# Demangling symbols from green hills rh850 compiled binary

Tags: symbols

I have a binary compiled in Rh850 using green hills compiler from the looks. Luckily, it still symbols attached ,but I am struggling to read the symbols and it is worth my time to demangle them. Is there a script or better yet a rule set that I can extract somehow to start this process? I am wanting to avoid the whole compiling binaries until I solve all the symbols myself.

I assume there is a symbol conversion table or something documented somewhere, but either will be great.

I found a couple of scripts, but they are very incomplete.

https://github.com/Chadderz121/ghs-demangle

https://github.com/jackwakefield/ghs-demangler

Comment: The second one credits GNU Libiberty, so are you sure `c++filt` and friends don't simply work out of the box? Also, please amend your question to tell us what exactly seems to be missing. But given what you've already found, it appears to be either verbatim or a modification of the GNU C++ symbol mangling.

Answer (score 1):

Without specifics, it's hard to say what exactly is missing in the standard demangler for you but this could be helpful:

https://github.com/kv59piaoxue/VxWork551/blob/master/source551/target/src/cplus/rts/demangler/etoa_decode.c

It contains a demangler for the so-called "EDG" (Edison Design Group) aka "cfront" mangling scheme which was used by most industry compilers before the arrival of the Itanium ABI mangling around GCC 3.0.